# Is it possible to upload file to dropbox with only file name(without path) using java.......?

Tags: java

In my web application i want to upload file to drop-box. I am getting file name from browser.Is it possible to upload file to drop-box with only file name.

Below the drop-box upload code with java.

```
File inputFile = new File("New Text Document.txt");
  System.out.println("inputFile.getAbsoluteFile(): " + inputFile);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
            DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
        System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

In the above code the place **New Text Document.txt** we have to provide total path of file.

please help me.Thanq

Comment: You'll have to write a code to scan the hard drive (or drives) to find the file specified and you'll have to have a policy for duplicated ones.